# Android values.xml returning error after adding ' compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0' '

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, android-xml

I'm using Android Studio and when I add `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'` and `compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'` in my `build.gradle` I got the following error in `values.xml`:

> Error:(524) Attribute "font" already defined with incompatible format.
>
> Error:(459) Original attribute defined here. Error:(524) Attribute
>   "font" already defined with incompatible format.
>
> Error:(459) Original attribute defined here. Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

[image]

Project `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
dependencies { provided fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0' compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
compile project(':commons-lang3-3.4')
compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.3'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
compile 'cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.1'
compile 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11'
compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-android:3.1.0'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
compile 'org.adw.library:discrete-seekbar:1.0.1'
compile 'com.microsoft.azure.android:azure-storage-android:0.6.0@aar'
compile project(':azure-notifications-handler-1.0.1')
compile project(':notification-hubs-0.4')
compile project(':gcm')
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0' 
 compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.2.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.4'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.relecotech.androidsparsh"
    versionCode 6
    versionName "4.2"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/MSFTSIG.RSA'
    exclude 'META-INF/MSFTSIG.SF'

}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

}
```

Comment: share your build.gradle

Comment: @ChethanShetty Ii share my gradle in Edited Question

Comment: Use all support libraries of same version. Build and let me know. if same error persist it can be more specific to android O.

Comment: @ChethanShetty i tried not working same error occurred